# Put string into files from a bash script with variables

Tags: bash

I need to create a log file, but impossible to do it with variables

I create a script with variable, creating file, puting informations into my variable, then at the end, i want to put the variable value into a file AND show it in console.

```
#!/bin/ksh

log=''

touch monLog.log

log="$log ===================================\n"
log="$log ================LOG================\n"
log="$log ===================================\n"

[...]

log="$log Division $division : aucun fichier pour la division\n"
log="$log Division $division inexistante\n" 

echo "$log" >> monLog.log
echo "$log"
echo "test fini"
```

This script give me the next result :

```
===================================
================LOG================
===================================

Division MADIVISION : aucun fichier pour la division
Division MADIVISION2 inexistante 

test fini
```

But, the cat monLog.log is empty...

echo of variable show me the good log, but the >> put nothing into the file
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Is this a possible copy/paste error?  Can you `ls -l` in the directory to see if you have another file that contains the desired contents?  For example, if you accidentally pasted `monLog.log^M` on the `>>` line, where `^M` is the literal carriage return character, you may end up with a file with that name containing the contents of your `log` variable.

You can do a `cat -v` of your script to check for mistakes like this.  The errant `^M` would show up with `cat -v`, but not `cat`.